# Retrofit 2.0 - How to get response body for 400 Bad Request error?

Tags: android, retrofit

So when I make a POST API call to my server, I get a 400 Bad Request error with JSON response.

```
{
    "userMessage": "Blah",
    "internalMessage": "Bad Request blah blah",
    "errorCode": 1
}
```

I call it by

```
Call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        //AA
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        //BB
    }
}
```

However the problem is that once I get the response, onFailure() is invoke so that //BB is called. Here, I have no way to access the JSON response.
When I log the api request and response, it doesn't show JSON response at all. And Throwable t is IOException. However, strangely, when I make the same call on Postman, it does return the expected JSON response with 400 error code.

So my question is how can I get the json response when I get 400 Bad Request error? Should I add something to okhttpclient?

Thanks

Comment: I think this answer would help you. [retrofit 400 Bad Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133621/retrofit-400-bad-request)

Comment: Did u manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 65):

You can do it in your `onResponse` method, remember **400** is a response status not an error:

```
if (response.code() == 400) {              
    Log.v("Error code 400",response.errorBody().string());
}
```

And you can handle any response code **except 200-300** with `Gson` like that:

```
if (response.code() == 400) {
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
   ErrorPojoClass mError=new ErrorPojoClass();
   try {
       mError= gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(),ErrorPojoClass.class);
       Toast.makeText(context, mError.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // handle failure to read error
   }        
}
```

Add this to your `build.gradle` : `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`

If you want create `Pojo` class go to [Json Schema 2 Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and paste your example `Json` response. Select source type **Json** and annotation **Gson** .

Comment: As I wrote, onResponse () is not executed at all. onFailure() is executed instead so there is no way for me to access response object :(

Comment: @user2062024 did you tried to log `call.request().body().toString()` and see whats wrong. Normally it must go in onResponse ,but if you provide more code and if possible Postman screenshot and i think about it.

Comment: @slanecek i am using Retrofit too and tried my code . Tried to request with bad body. And it goes to onResponse.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz You're right, my bad. RC 400 was an error back in Retrofit 1.x

Comment: @user2062024 i am saying again response is response and doesnt matter which code you getting like 200, 400, 401 . On failure triggering only when url isn't valid or you have connection problems. Or server read/write process timeout. If you see this issue and read JakeWharton's comment you will understand : https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1260

Comment: no wonder I can't get result with calling response.body().string()...Thanks for sharing the actual way is to call it this way response.errorBody().string()

Answer (score 21):

> You can try the below code to get 400 response. You can get error response from errorBody() method.

```
Call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        //get success and error response here
 if (response.code() == 400) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                        String userMessage = jsonObject.getString("userMessage");
                        String internalMessage = jsonObject.getString("internalMessage");
                        String errorCode = jsonObject.getString("errorCode");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        //get failure response here
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed method name from `toString` to `string`

Answer (score 13):

> Handle **ErrorResponse** with your class object

**Kotlin**

```
val errorResponse = Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()!!.charStream(), ErrorResponse::class.java)
```

**Java**

```
ErrorResponse errorResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody.charStream(),ErrorResponse.class)
```

Comment: Do you know why logging response.body() shows the content but response.errorBody() shows something like this
> http3.ResponseBody$Companion$asResponseBody$1@4924754

Answer (score 8):

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    DialogHelper.dismiss();

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        // Success
    } else {
        try {
            JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: yes working! great!

Answer (score 5):

**First step:**

Create your POJO class for error response. In my case, `ApiError.java`

```
public class ApiError {

    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    @Expose
    private String errorMessage;

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage= errorMessage;
    }
}
```

**Second Step:**

Write below code in your api callback.

```
Call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Response<RegistrationResponse> response) 
     {
         if (response.isSuccessful()) {
             // do your code here
         } else if (response.code() == 400) {
             Converter<ResponseBody, ApiError> converter =
                            ApiClient.retrofit.responseBodyConverter(ApiError.class, new Annotation[0]);

                    ApiError error;

                    try {
                        error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
                        Log.e("error message", error.getErrorMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
         //do your failure handling code here
     }
}
```

Here `ApiClient.retrofit` is your retrofit instance which is static.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest solution,

If you want to handle the response from onFailure method:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    HttpException httpException = (HttpException) t;
    String errorBody = httpException.response().errorBody().string();
    // use Gson to parse json to your Error handling model class
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = Gson().fromJson(errorBody, ErrorResponse.class);
}
```

Or if you are using rxjava Observable with Kotlin, handle it from error body:

```
{ error ->
    val httpException :HttpException = error as HttpException
    val errorBody: String = httpException.response().errorBody()!!.string()
    // use Gson to parse json to your Error handling model class
    val errorResponse: ErrorResponse = 
       Gson().fromJson(errorBody, ErrorResponse::class.java)
}
```

**Don't forget to properly handle json to class conversion (use try-catch if not sure).**

Answer (score 4):

I got similar issue, but existing code was stick to RxJava 2 chain.
Here's my solution:

```
   public static <T> Observable<T> rxified(final Call<T> request, final Class<T> klazz) {
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<T>() {

        AtomicBoolean justDisposed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        @Override
        public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<T> emitter) throws Exception {

            emitter.setDisposable(new Disposable() {
                @Override
                public void dispose() {
                    request.cancel();
                    justDisposed.set(true);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isDisposed() {
                    return justDisposed.get();
                }
            });

            if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                request.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, retrofit2.Response<T> response) {
                        if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                emitter.onNext(response.body());
                                emitter.onComplete();

                            } else {
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                try {
                                    T errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), klazz);
                                    emitter.onNext(errorResponse);
                                    emitter.onComplete();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    emitter.onError(e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
                        if (!emitter.isDisposed()) emitter.onError(t);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

transforming 400-like responses into rx chain is pretty simple:

```
Call<Cat> request = catApi.getCat();
rxified(request, Cat.class).subscribe( (cat) -> println(cat) );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can handle the response message
I am handling for error 500 you can add as much you want

```
                switch (response.code()) {
                    case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                        break;
                    case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED:
                        callback.onUnAuthentic();
                        break;
                    case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                        try {
                            String errorResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(errorResponse);
                            String message = "Error";
                            if (object.has("Message"))
                                message = String.valueOf(object.get("Message"));
                            callback.onError(message);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT:
                    case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT:
                    default:
                        callback.onNetworkError();
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
 if (throwable is HttpException && (throwable!!.code() == 400 || throwable!!.code()==404)){
                               var responseBody = throwable!!.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
                               val jsonObject = JSONObject(responseBody!!.trim())
                               var message = jsonObject.getString("message")
                               tvValMsg.set(message)
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are getting **400(Bad Request)** by using retrofit first make sure are are setting **input to API is Only Model** class, If not then replace input request by Model class and then check you will get Success response.

> ```
> @POST("api/users/CreateAccount")
> Call<CreateAccount> createAccount(@Body CreateAccount model, @Header("Content-Type") String content_type);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To handle 400 Bad Request error in response use following code.

```
         if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body().getStatus().equals(1)) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(UploadPDFActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                Log.e("hello 4001", "else condition");

                if (statusCode == 400) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        try {
                            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                            String entityId = jsonObject.getString("entity_id");
                            String errorMessage = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            String errorStatus = jsonObject.getString("status");
                            Log.e("hello entityId", entityId);
                            Log.e("hello errorMessage", errorMessage);
                            Log.e("hello errorStatus", errorStatus);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadPDFActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                     }
                      else {
                    // Handle other error cases
                }
            }
        }
```